# AS3 Error 1000 on Vector

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

So I've never worked with Vectors in Flash before and I wanted to write a little test application with a Vector using a custom object. But I'm getting: `error 1000: Ambiguous reference to Vector` when I try launching the application. I can't figure out for the life of me what's wrong. I tried not using a custom object and just instantiating a string Vector from an online tutorial and I'm getting the same thing.

Here's what I got:

```
package
{
import TestPlayer; // The custom player class
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Vector extends MovieClip
{
    private var array:Array = new Array();
    private var vector:Vector.<TestPlayer>;

    public function Vector()
    {
        array[0] = [0, 0, "Bob", false];
        array[1] = [1, 0, "Frank", true];
        array[2] = [2, 1, "Sarah", true];
        Load();
    }

    private function Load():void
    {
        var aPlayer:Player = null;
        vector = new Vector.<TestPlayer>();

        try
        {
            var numRows:int = array.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
            {
                aPlayer = new Player();

                aPlayer.playerID = array[i][0];
                aPlayer.playerName = array[i][1];
                aPlayer.playerTypeID = array[i][2];
                aPlayer.hasProgress = array[i][3];

                vector.push(aPlayer);
            }
        }
        catch (error:Error) { }
    }
}
```

The custom player class looks like this:

```
package
{
    public class TestPlayer
    {
        private var _playerID:int;
        private var _playerName:String = "";

        public function get playerID():int 
        {
            return _playerID;
        }

        public function set playerID(value:int):void 
        {
            _playerID = value;
        }

        public function get playerName():String 
        {
            return _playerName;
        }

        public function set playerName(value:String):void 
        {
            _playerName = value;
        }
            [...]
    }
}
```

I don't know if it matters, but I'm working in Flash CS5, and I have a blank FLA that imports the class. No other errors so far. Hope you can help. Let me know if you need anymore info, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ambiguous reference is because you've got a naming collision. The class you've written is named "Vector", which it can't distinguish from the top-level class `Vector`. The fix is simple, avoid naming your classes the same as a pre-existing class.

If both classes belong to separate namespaces, you *can* reuse class names, as long as you use thier fully-qualified name whenever you call the class.

Assume you have a class:

```
package foo.bar
{
  class MovieClip
  ...
}
```

You could instantiate both types of MovieClips as follows:

```
flashMovieClip = new flash.display.MovieClip();
myMovieClip = new foo.bar.MovieClip();
```

Unfortunately, both your `Vector` and the flash `Vector` exist in the top-level namespace, so (AFAIK) there's no way of removing the ambiguity without renaming your class. For simplicity sake, avoid naming collisions and you should be golden.

Comment: omg I feel so stupid right now. :( I hate missing the little things like that. Thanks a lot, that fixed it. I'll mark right in a sec, stack won't let me.